# Why Chrome extension works only when the service worker inspector is open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple extension that opens a new tab once the last tab is closed.
It works as expected when the extension's service worker inspector AKA console is open and not working when the console is not open.

Why is that?

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Last tab",
  "description": "Last tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(async function() {

    const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ lastFocusedWindow: true });

    if (!tabs.length) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'chrome://newtab/' });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/462939) and an incorrect condition in your code.

When devtools window is active it is mistakenly processed by chrome.tabs.query and since it doesn't have any tabs the result is 0, then your code successfully proceeds to opening a tab.

When devtools window is closed, the actual browser window is correctly processed and an actual number of tabs is returned, which is not 0, so `!tabs.length` is false.

In Chrome the situation you check for cannot even happen because when the last tab is closed, the entire window is closed so `lastFocusedWindow: true` will use a different window. If it was the last window, the entire browser terminates.

The solution would be to check for closing of the last window and using the special `background` permission that makes your extension run in the system tray even after the last browser window is closed.

manifest.json:

```json
  "permissions": [
    "background"
  ]
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(async () => {
  if (!(await chrome.tabs.query({})).length) {
    chrome.windows.create({});
  }
});
```

It would make sense to keep the last window's position:

```js
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(savePos);
chrome.windows.onBoundsChanged.addListener(savePos);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(savePos);
async function savePos() {
  chrome.storage.session.set({
    pos: (await chrome.windows.getAll({windowTypes: ['normal']}))
      .map(w => [w.left, w.top, w.width, w.height]),
  })
}
```

Reading/using it is up to the reader.

Comment: The code you've provided does help and at least it works now, unlike my code. One thing though, this approach makes it impossible to close the window by well, closing the window :) If you try to close it - the script opens a new one. The behavior I was trying to recreate is basically what Opera does (I am switching off it and trying to recreate this functionality in Chrome) - when you close the last tab - it just opens a new tab for you, but when you close a window - it closes the browser. You still can close the windows via menu but it is not as convenient. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: One more thing, I was trying to understand the nature of the Chrome issue but I could not - when I print `tabs` retrieved like in my example - I see only the tabs from my window, without filters - all tabs from all windows. So I guess the root cause here is inability of the extension to work when the last window is closed and it can be fixed, as you suggested, by using the `background` permission. Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to replicate Opera's behavior in Chrome because the window is closed automatically when the last tab is closed.

Comment: It is opening now even with the console closed. Dit the bug got fixed?